# Hiding links from certain roles in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization

So this may sound a dumb question, but how do I show a link only for an admin user?

Suppose an ordinary user sees the following links:
Home / About / Contact

And an admin user sees the following links:
Home / About / Contact / Admin

I tried restricting in the controller and linking the controller on the menu. But it still shows the link for everyone, just doesn't allow access to anyone but admin

Can the views be overloaded?

Comment: It's not just hide, you must evaluate the role of user logged... there is so many answer to this kind of question

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Depending on what sort of Membership/User provider you are using, you should just be able to check directly from the View if the user is logged in and in the specific role.

So you would end up with something like;

```
@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Home") 
@Html.ActionLink("About", "Home") 
@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Home") 
@if ( User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ){
    if ( User.IsInRole("Admin") ){
        @Html.ActionLink("Admin", "AdminController")        
    }
}
```

And remember to add `[Authorize]` attribute to your `Admin` action method:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public ActionResult Admin()
{
    // ...
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Is a best practice (or perhaps due to clarity) to check if the user is authenticated **and** if they're in a certain role? The way I figure, they won't be in any role unless they tell the site who they are, which implies prior authentication. Please note that I'm **not questioning** the choice but **merely wondering**. My skills in security are like penguins' in flight - seen others do it, never done myself. (Difference being, I'm using the holidays to ambitiously change that state, unlike the lazy penguins, hihi.)

Comment: The `Authorize` attribute will check that the user is authenticated by default and then you can optionally add in the roles.

Comment: Oh, I realize that was unclear (apparently, mind-reading isn't your strong side, hehe). I'm referring to the line 4 and 5 in the **first** sample (CSHTML file, Razor markup).

Comment: How does this work with AD groups? I can't get my actionlinks to hide in my table when I use this `@if(User.IsInRole("DOMAIN\\Group")`